# Missing dependency for method public entities in Netbeans restful web services

Tags: web-services, rest, netbeans, jersey, composite-key

I am deploying a restful web services using Netbeans EE6 and jersey libraries with the tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html.

When I create a restful web services from entities that hold composite primary keys in the database, the project gives me an error when I try to test the web services:

> SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public entities.RMSchedule service.RMScheduleFacadeREST.find(entities.RMSchedulePK) at parameter at index 0
>     SEVERE: Method, public entities.RMSchedule service.RMScheduleFacadeREST.find(entities.RMSchedulePK), annotated with GET of resource, class service.RMScheduleFacadeREST, is not recognized as valid resource method.

Is the error due to composite primary keys or is there a step that I should include?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having same issue, have you found solution?

Comment: unfortunately no, i removed all composite keys from my database, which actually was more efficient as I ran into issues later on. I also reverted to using Java ee 5 with netbeans version 7.0.1 due to other issues, such as the absence of expandLevel, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is related to Netbeans bug:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=208375

When creating entity class which has composite primary keys,
two entity files are created. `(ex CustomerEntity.jave, CustomerEntityPK.java)`

Then if you choose to create the servlet from the entity class, the servlet comes with automatically generated code such as below:

```
    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") CustomerEntityPK id) {　//error
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public CustomerEntity find(@PathParam("id") CustomerEntityPK id) { //error
        return super.find(id);
    }
```

**The issue is that argument being passed to the servlet methods is CustomerEntityPK which has composite primary key.**

If you change the argument type to something like String then the error went away in my case.

```
    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void remove(@PathParam("id") String id) {　//type set to String now
        super.remove(super.find(id));
    }
```

But in my project I did not need such auto generated code so I simply choose to create servlet class by hand and has no problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In the latter, it is being treated as a simple key then

Comment: I think if composite key should be passed, PathParam variable needs to be something like JSON {key1:foo, key2:bar} or other format. In my project we use JSON for this purpose.